# Slow SSH - Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out - no systemd

Tags: ssh, timeout, dbus, devuan-linux

I run Devuan Linux, which still uses sysvinit and does not use systemd. For a while now, I've noticed SSH logins are very slow. The log (/var/log/auth.log) indicates that DBus is timing out:

```
Feb 19 10:41:07 <hostname> sshd[22198]: Accepted publickey for gargravarr from <IP> port 34654 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<keyID>
Feb 19 10:41:07 <hostname> sshd[22198]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user gargravarr(uid=<UID>) by (uid=0)
Feb 19 10:41:32 <hostname> dbus-daemon[6674]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Feb 19 10:41:32 <hostname> sshd[22198]: pam_elogind(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Searching around, I can see this is not an uncommon problem in the systemd world. However, I am not using systemd, and according to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/707377/slow-ssh-login-activation-of-org-freedesktop-login1-timed-out), DBus was patched in version 1.11.10 to fix this, and I'm running 1.12.20.

OS: Devuan 4 'Chimaera'
Kernel: 5.10.0-11

I have 3 other Devuan servers almost identically configured and none of them exhibit this problem, only this one. Restarting dbus does not help nor does rebooting the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was never able to find an answer to this problem and ended up reinstalling the OS. If you're having a similar problem and found this, my sympathies.